Accessing Private Service in AppRunner
I have a private service, say, employee-service running in AppRunner which is supposed to be accessible only within my VPC.
AppRunner generates a private endpoint https://bf8dsd7yud.myregion.awsapprunner.com/. I would like to access it as https://employee-service/ within my VPC as we do for kubernetes clusterIP. is this possible?

You could accomplish that using a Route53 private hosted zoned. You would need to create a CNAME, for example:
CNAME - employee-service.internaldmain -> https://bf8dsd7yud.myregion.awsapprunner.com

I tried that. It did not work. The problem is - "https"

If you use HTTPS, your service must be running on port 443. The DNS (Route 53) is only responsible for translating the domain name to an IP address at Layer 3. It has nothing to do with Layer 4, which handles TCP in this case.

It is not like I use HTTPs. AppRunner urls are auto generated. They use https. Looks like we need to register our domain to get the urls for our domain.

Yeah, you're right! What problem do you have when you use the Route53 private hosted zone? Is it not resolving the IP, timeout or something else?
